# Youtube API NoLinkedYouTubeAccount Error

Tags: youtube-api

using of youube api getting this error

> Error Domain=com.google.GDataServiceDomain Code=403 "The operation
>   couldn’t be completed. (com.google.GDataServiceDomain error 403.)"
>   UserInfo=0x7676020 {Error=NoLinkedYouTubeAccount,
>   error=NoLinkedYouTubeAccount}

Comment: Have you tried using a google account with an associated youtube account?

Comment: Please post the code that prompted this error.

Answer (score 0):

You recieve this error since you are using Service account authentication. 
*The service account flow supports server-to-server interactions that do not access user information. However, the YouTube Data API does not support this flow. Since there is no way to link a Service Account to a YouTube account, attempts to authorize requests with this flow will generate a NoLinkedYouTubeAccount error.* 
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/authentication

You may try to use another type of authentication, such as server-side or installed application, however user should allow to use his account.

If you want to create an app which will allow different users to add videos to your own channel, than you can try ClientLogin authentication protocol. 
Look here for more info https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_clientlogin#ClientLogin_Authentication

This protocol is deprecated but I have not found any way to resolve problem.